# The simplest way to pow using only simple arithmetic

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

i want to get function $f(x, a) = x^a$, 
for both x and a - real numbers, that uses only + - * /. So only way I found is: get taylor series for $$x^a = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{{a}^{n}{log}^{n}(x)}{n!}$$, use taylor series for log and found an answer, but it has complexity of $O(n^2)$ and seems be a bad solution.

Comment: The word *complexity* implies that you are trying to implement this in a computer program. If that is indeed the case, then your **real** numbers are in fact "only" **rational** numbers, and for that I can give you the answer (if you're interested).

Comment: I want a solution for **real** numbers, but solution for rational also come down. It's better than nothing.

Comment: See answer for $a\in\mathbb{Q}$ below...

Comment: What is the exact range of real numbers that you want to support (argument and exponent) ? Fixed or floating-point ? Expected accuracy ?

Comment: Doesn't your DSP system come with an FP library with a pow function ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, i'm expecting function that takes two doubles and returns double value. So expected accuracy comes from IEEE754

Comment: Efficient techniques have been developed over time, using polynomial approximation among others, and complete solutions are not trivial. You could consider taking a look at fdlibm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found my own solution for any a and b. But your post was very helpful. It gave me this idea.

Everybody knows that $${a}^{b} = {e}^{b*ln(a)}$$ We also know that $${a}^{b} = {a}^{n}{a}^{f}, n \in Z, f \in (0..1)$$ Idea is: we can find easily  ${a}^{n}$, after we can find $${a}^{f} = {e}^{f*ln(a)}$$ 
$ln(a)$ can be also easily find by integrating $$\int_{1}^{a}\frac{dt}{t}$$ by Simpson's rule. And exponent can be easily find by taylor series 
$${e}^{x} = \sum \frac{{x}^{n}}{n!}$$

so here is my C++ realisation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;


double simpson(double(*f)(double), double a, double b)
{
    double result = (b - a) / 6;
    result *= f(a) + 4 * f((a + b) / 2) + f(b);
    return result;
}

double f(double x)
{
    return 1 / x;
}

double my_ln(double x)
{
    if (x == 1)
        return 0;
    if (x <= 0)
        return NAN;
    double result = 0;
    double step = (x - 1) / 100;
    for (double a = 1; a < x; a += step)
        result += simpson(f, a, a + step);
    return result;
}

double my_exp(double x, double epsilon)
{
    double result = 1;
    double m = x;
    for (int i = 2; abs(m) >= epsilon; i++)
    {
        result += m;
        m *= x / i;
    }
    return result;
}

double my_pow(double a, double b, double epsilon)
{
    if (b < 0)
        return my_pow(1 / a, -b, epsilon);
    int div = (int)b;
    double integerPart = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < div; i++)
        integerPart *= a;
    return integerPart * my_exp((b - div) * my_ln(a), epsilon);
}

int main()
{   
    cout << my_ln(15) << endl;
    cout << my_exp(3, 0.001) << endl;
    cout << my_pow(2, 3, 0.001) << endl;
}
```

---

easier way is a bit more compact:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;


double simpson(double(*f)(double), double a, double b)
{
    double result = (b - a) / 6;
    result *= f(a) + 4 * f((a + b) / 2) + f(b);
    return result;
}

double f(double x)
{
    return 1 / x;
}

double my_ln(double x)
{
    if (x == 1)
        return 0;
    if (x <= 0)
        return NAN;
    double result = 0;
    double step = (x - 1) / 100;
    for (double a = 1; a < x; a += step)
        result += simpson(f, a, a + step);
    return result;
}

double my_pow(double a, double b, double epsilon)
{
    double result = 1, tmp = 1;
    double m = b * my_ln(a);
    for (int i = 1; abs(tmp) >= epsilon; i++)
    {
        tmp *= m / i;
        result += tmp;
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    cout << my_ln(15) << endl;
    cout << my_pow(2, 3, 0.001) << endl;
}
```

from formulas $$x^a = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{{a}^{n}{log}^{n}(x)}{n!}$$ I dunno why I didn't use it first time.

Comment: You do realize that it's going to work only for a small range of values (due to computational overflow), right? A class that supports arithmetic operations on an unlimited-size rational number (using an unlimited-size integer numerator and an unlimited-size integer denominator), might be useful here. You can see an example of such class in the link that I provided at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Not rly. For example, for `12.1` and `32.5` result is `1.55069+035`, wolframalpha give the same result. I used precision `epsilon = 0.00001`

Comment: I meant for calculating power.

Comment: If you mean that I'm using float-point instead of rational number, it's NP because I was looking for more applied solution, that do not take a lot of time for fairly accurate result

Comment: No, I mean that the maximum value that a `double` can store is around $2^{53}$.

Comment: not rly, up to ${10}^{308}$, doubles below ${2}^{53}$ are integers, but bigger numbers can be also presented the expense of accuracy

Comment: So you "lose" in either case (either on accuracy or on size).

Comment: Not to mention the fact that you're using FP operations, which are potentially "more expensive" on some architectures (fixed-point processors in particular).

Comment: For example above,  N=898611 and D=1250000 as you said. And i think that $x^N$ and $x^D$ are I'm not sure that this numbers can be calculated within a reasonable time. And i really dunno which architecture you talking about - x86/ARM both supports double-point at same speed as fixed-point. And AFAIK Itanium too.

Comment: DSP architectures mostly... In any case, I agree that calculating $x^{2.7188888}$ is probably much faster than calculating $\sqrt[898611]{x^{1250000}}$... :)

Answer (score 2):

Answering for $a\in\mathbb{Q}$ (the set of rational numbers):

- Let $\displaystyle a=\frac{N}{D}$
- $\displaystyle x^a=\sqrt[D]{x^N}$
- $\displaystyle x^N$ can be calculated easily
- $\displaystyle \sqrt[D]{x^N}$ can be calculated with the following (converging) sequence:

  - $\displaystyle S_0=x^N$
  - $\displaystyle S_{n+1}=S_n-\frac{{S_n}^D-x^N}{D\cdot{S_n}^{D-1}}$

---

Here is a method for calculating the numerator and the denominator of a rational value:

```
Function (Input value, Output numerator, Output denominator):

    Set numerator   = 0
    Set denominator = 1

    If value > 0:
        Set sign = 1
    Else:
        Set sign  = -1
        Set value = -value

    While value > 0:
        Set intValue    = Int(value)
        Set value       = value - intValue
        Set numerator   = numerator + intValue
        Set value       = value * 2
        Set numerator   = numerator * 2
        Set denominator = denominator * 2

    If numerator > denominator:
        Set hi = numerator
        Set lo = denominator
    Else:
        Set hi = denominator
        Set lo = numerator

    While True:
        Set rem = hi mod lo
        If rem == 0:
            Break
        Set hi = lo
        Set lo = rem

    Set numerator   = numerator   / lo
    Set denominator = denominator / lo
    Set denominator = denominator * sign
```

---

In addition, you might find [this](https://github.com/barakman/Num) C++ implementation useful.

Comment: Thanks. But now i got that i cannot get N and D although I can get only K. So for example, i have a nomber a = `2,7188888`. So K here can be easily got by `K = (int) a`, but how to convert `0.7188888` to N/D although it's rational?..

Comment: @AlexJoukovsky: You're welcome. First of all, $N=7188888$ and $D=10000000$. Of course, you can calculate $\gcd(N,D)=8$ and then reduce these values to $N=898611$ and $D=1250000$.

Comment: see my answer below. I hope it's nice

Comment: @AlexJoukovsky: I've simplified the answer above to exclude the integer part ($K$), leaving only the numerator ($N$) and the denominator ($D$). I also added a pseudo-code method for extracting the numerator and the denominator of a value represented in *Floating-Point* format. Finally, I added a link to a C++ implementation which includes calculating Power and Root of rational numbers.